# Can't select sub aggregation in Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I get these results in my Elastic query:

```
"Results" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "73c47133-8656-45e7-9499-14f52df07b70",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "foo" : {
            "doc_count" : 40,
            "bar" : {
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "customscore" : {
                "value" : 10.496919917864476
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

I am trying to get a list of anonymous objects with the `key` field as the key and `customscore` field as the value.

No matter what I try, I can't seem to write code in Nest that accesses the `customscore` value. Apparently, I'm the very first person in the world to use nested Aggregations with the Nest library. Either that, or the documentation is very lacking. I can easily reach the Buckets:

```
response?.Aggregations.Terms("Results").Buckets;
```

But I have no idea what to do with this object. `Buckets` contains several objects, which I would assume I could navigate by doing this:

```
bucketObject["foo"]["bar"]["customscore"]
```

But apparently not. I have found solutions that use for loops, solutions with long Linq queries, and all of them seem to return `null` for me. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nested-aggregation-usage.html

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you so much for all your help these last 2 weeks. I have hacked a solution together by just converting the Buckets property to a NewtonSoft `JObject`, and using NewtonSoft to get the data I want. This is 3 lines of code, two of which are very simple Linq Select queries. It's hacky but very short and readable. And surprisingly, shorter than any of the official Elastic examples I've seen so far.

Comment: What's the query, and the full response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following query, which I *think* would match the response in the question

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var response = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .Index("some_index")
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("Results", t => t
            .Field("some_field")
            .Aggregations(aa => aa  
                .Filter("foo", f => f
                    .Filter(q => q.MatchAll())
                    .Aggregations(aaa => aaa
                        .Filter("bar", ff => ff
                            .Filter(q => q.MatchAll())
                            .Aggregations(aaaa => aaaa
                                .ValueCount("customscore", vc => vc
                                    .Field("some_other_field")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

To get a collection of anonymous types would be

```cs
var kvs = response.Aggregations.Terms("Results").Buckets
    .Select(b => new 
    { 
        key = b.Key, 
        value = b.Filter("foo").Filter("bar").ValueCount("customscore").Value 
    });
```

[`.Aggregations` exposes methods that convert the `IAggregate` response to the expected type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html#handling-aggregate-response)

Comment: Thanks Russ, this works for me. Sorry I did not reply to your previous comment, I was busy sleeping. :)

One thing though, I'm probably very bad at searching but even with Google, and knowing what I'm looking for, I can't find code examples using Filter and ValueCount on the ElasticSearch documentation pages. Considering how easy these methods make searching through the whole json response from Elastic, the documentation might want to cover this topic more in depth. It could also be due to me being relatively new in Elastic.